# Отображение контента за уведомлением

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
  <script>
    let canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20);

    prompt("Test");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Можно ли отображать контент страницы когда выскакивает уведомление?

Comment: А если показывать его чуть позже?) `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ // Всё что будет тут, сработает после загрузки HTML })`

Comment: Отображать контент после уведомления? если да - перенесите prompt в первую строку сразу после тега script

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Нет, хотелось бы чтобы прям во время уведомления на заднем фоне был виден контент. Я думаю можно реализовать через <iframe>